# How to load a file from the same directory as the script, in MongoDB shell

Tags: mongodb, cron, mongo-shell

I'm running a bash script that executes a javascript file in the Mongo shell:

outerscript.sh

```
SCRIPTPATH="$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P )"
LOGDIR=~/logs
LOGFILE=$LOGDIR/outerscript.log
mongo < $SCRIPTPATH/jsscript.js >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
```

jsscript.js

```
load(myVars.js);
```

MongoDB is v4.0.19

The script may be run locally or on a remote server, and it may be run from the command line or from a cron job, and I want to load in myVars.js which is always in the same folder as outerscript.sh.

I can't find a way to load myVars.js when running outerscript.sh from a cron job.

pwd() returns the user's home directory, not the location of the currently running script, so this doesn't work for the cron job:

```
load(pwd() + '/myVars.js');
```

This also doesn't work for the cron job, I'm guessing for the same reason:

```
load('./myVars.js');
```

Alternatively, is there another way to pass variables into my JavaScript file, that will still let me log output to the logfile? As far as I can tell, you can't combine --eval with logging output to a file, and I haven't found a way to read environment variables directly from inside the JS file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a redirect, try `mongo $SCRIPTPATH/jsscript.js >> $LOGFILE 2>&1`

See

```
$ mongo --help
MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
usage: mongo [options] [db address] [file names (ending in .js)]
db address can be:
  foo                   foo database on local machine
  192.168.0.5/foo       foo database on 192.168.0.5 machine
  192.168.0.5:9999/foo  foo database on 192.168.0.5 machine on port 9999
  mongodb://192.168.0.5:9999/foo  connection string URI can also be used
```

You can use [cat()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cat/index.html) in your js script.

e.g.

```
echo '{"path": "some folder"}' > /tmp/foldername.js
```

Then in your js script:

```
var txt = cat("/tmp/foldername.js")
var folderObj = JSON.parse(txt)
```

Then you can use `folderObj` object in your script.

Why do you not simply use `SCRIPTPATH="$(dirname "$0")"`?

Comment: https://electrictoolbox.com/bash-script-directory/ I want to get SCRIPTPATH as the correct absolute path regardless of where the bash script is run from

Comment: That is a clever solution! I prefer load() over cat(), and included SCRIPTPATH like this: echo 'const path = '\'"${SCRIPTPATH}"\'';' > /tmp/foldername.js. Then in the JS: load('/tmp/foldername.js'); print(path);

Comment: I use [readlink](https://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink) to get the correct absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Wernfried Domscheit answered my question perfectly and I have accepted that answer.

I also worked out how to pass in environment variables as parameters and am posting it here just in case it helps anybody.

outerscript.sh

```
SCRIPTPATH="$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P )"

ENVVARS='var mongoAddress='\'"${MONGO_ADDRESS}"\''; var databaseName='\'"${DATABASE_NAME}"\'

mongo --eval "${ENVVARS}" $SCRIPTPATH/jsscript.js >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
```

jsscript.js

```
print(mongoAddress);
print(databaseName);
```